# Data fails to get synced on message's extended item properties using O365 REST API

Tags: office-addins, outlook-restapi

**Problem**

We have an Outlook add-in that uses Outlook Office365 REST API to update mail item properties. One example is writing some custom metadata to the SingleValueExtendedProperties field of a mail-item.

Since yesterday we started noticing that the values that we write on the extended properties are not getting synced to the exchange server.

**Steps to reproduce**

- PATCH on the Messages resource to update item properties with some data

```
Method: PATCH
URL: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages('<messageId>')
Request Body: 
{
    "SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "PropertyId": "{propertyId}",
            "Value": “{\”color\":\"green\"}"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Use GET API to get the latest values.

```
Method: GET
URL: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages('<messageId>')?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq ‘{propertyId}’)
```

**Observation**

The PATCH call ran through successfully, but the GET call didn't return the latest values. The update that we tried yesterday also has not yet synced.

**Environment**

- Client: Microsoft Outlook for Mac
- Build Version: 16.42 (20101102)

**Note**

We have already started using the Microsoft Graph API in the new software that we are building since that’s the recommended one for interacting with mail/events. We still rely on Office365 API in our current systems to fetch/update data.

Is there a known issue that could be causing this? Is anyone else experiencing this?